# Why is d3.select().style() not applied to <div>-elements?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been staring at this for a while now and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm basically trying to make my own implementation of this example: http://vallandingham.me/building_a_bubble_cloud.htm

In a similar fashion as the article I have a DOM structure that looks like this

```
<div id="d3">
    <div id="labels">
        <div class="label">Label</div>
    </div>
    <svg> << SVG-stuff >> </svg>
</div>
```

As far as I understand it, in the article the label divs are positioned with the .style() function inside d3's tick function. Thusly:

```
d3.selectAll(".label")
   .style("left", function(d) { return d.x - (d.dx / 2) + "px"; })
   .style("left", function(d) { return d.x - (d.dx / 2) + "px"; })
```

BUT: when this is run, no styles are applied to the elements!

What is it that I am missing? How come this works in the example?

Comment: "no styles are not applied to the elements" I assume you mean "no styles are applied to the elements". Did you check whether the styles are set or are you simply not seeing a change? Any error messages? Note that you need to have bound data to the elements you select in order for this to work.

Comment: Works for me in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/1w59vqvp/1/

You will need to add `position = "absolute";` if you don't already have

Comment: Thank you guys! It turns out that the culprit was that `d.dx` was indeed `undefined`. I suppose since the functions do not return anything no styles are applied, not even `style="left: ;"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well im happy to answer this one myself, just in case someone else is confused about .style()

The problem in the above case is that `d.dx` is undefined which means the function doesn't return anything.

I simply didn't realize that if this is the case, not even `<div style="left: ; rigt: ;">` is applied.

`.style()`does indeed work on div elements anywhere in the DOM, as long as it's arguments are defined:

`.style("left", function(d) { return d.x + "px"; })`

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else sees this in the future, make SURE the style you are trying to apply is valid. I was trying to set a  element's "text-anchor" style to "right", and it just wouldn't go! Turns out it's "end", not "right".